# How draw a route in Google Maps as i goes on clicking on Google map?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api

I wanted to get route in Google map whenever I click on the road map of Google. What I mean by click is that when I can click one place then other and so on, but route to each click must be generated from previous click. Route must be shortest route from one point to other. I must be able to drag that click point when required and then new route must be generated for last two click.

Can any one suggest how i should do this?

Note: No marker required.

Hope could have express my problem effectively.

Comment: Hi Pari, It's easy to save  a Google Maps route to Kml file. Please follow these instructions: http://goo.gl/BAelL

Comment: Thanks Jorge i wanted javascript code for google APi for this task.